# How to extract features from an image for training a CNN model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am working on a project to classify waste as plastics and non plastics using only.images to train them.However i still dont know what features does the model take into account while classifyimg them.I am using CNN,however the accuracy of prediction is still not up to the mark.
The reason why i went to CNN because there is no specific feature to distinguish plastics from others.Is there any other way to approach this problem? 
     For eg If i train the images of cats,my Neural Network learns what is a cat however i do not explicitly give features is the same case valid here too?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to extract the Features from the Pre-Trained Convolutional Neural Network, **`VGGNet, VGG16`**.

**Code to reuse the Convolutional Base is:**

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
include_top=False,
input_shape=(150, 150, 3)) # This is the Size of your Image
```

The final feature map has shape (4, 4, 512). That’s the feature on top of which you’ll stick a densely connected classifier.

**There are 2 ways to extract Features:**

1. **FAST FEATURE EXTRACTION WITHOUT DATA AUGMENTATION:** Running the convolutional base over your dataset, recording its output to a
   Numpy array on disk, and then using this data as input to a standalone, densely
   connected classifier similar to those you saw in part 1 of this book. This solution is fast and cheap to run, because it only requires running the convolutional base once for every input image, and the convolutional base is by far the most expensive part of the pipeline. But for the same reason, this technique won’t allow you to use data augmentation.

Code for extracting Features using this method is shown below:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
base_dir = '/Users/fchollet/Downloads/cats_and_dogs_small'
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'validation')
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
batch_size = 20
def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 4, 4, 512))
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory, target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='binary')
    i=0
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
        labels[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
return features, labels
train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, 2000)
validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(validation_dir,1000)
test_features, test_labels = extract_features(test_dir, 1000)

train_features = np.reshape(train_features, (2000, 4*4* 512))
validation_features = np.reshape(validation_features, (1000, 4*4* 512))
test_features = np.reshape(test_features, (1000, 4*4* 512))

from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', input_dim=4 * 4 * 512))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5), 
    loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(train_features, train_labels, epochs=30,
batch_size=20, validation_data=(validation_features, validation_labels))
```

> Training is very fast, because you only have to deal with two Dense
>   layers—an epoch takes less than one second even on CPU

2. **FEATURE EXTRACTION WITH DATA AUGMENTATION:** Extending the model you have (conv_base) by adding Dense layers on top, and running the whole thing end to end on the input data. This will allow you to use data augmentation, because every input image goes through the convolutional base every time it’s seen by the model. But for the same reason, this technique is far more expensive than the first

Code for the same is shown below:

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import optimizers
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,rotation_range=40,
width_shift_range=0.2,height_shift_range=0.2,shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,horizontal_flip=True,fill_mode='nearest')
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,target_size=(150, 150), batch_size=20, class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
validation_dir,
target_size=(150, 150),
batch_size=20,
class_mode='binary')
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=100,   epochs=30, validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=50)
```

For more details, please refer [Section 5.3.1](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.3-using-a-pretrained-convnet.ipynb) of the book, "Deep Learning with Python", authored by Father of Keras, "Francois Chollet"